# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:

Tags: java, sql, dynamic-sql

I'm getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3840)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInt(PreparedStatement.java:3784)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:4052)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:816)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
```

When i'm trying to execute this class:

```
public List<CandidateDO> getCandidateList(final JobDO currentJob) {
    List<CandidateDO> appliedCandidateList = new ArrayList<CandidateDO>();
    CandidateDO candidate = new CandidateDO();
    String query = "SET @sql = NULL;";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(query);

    query = "SELECT\n"
            + "  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT\n"
            + "    CONCAT(\n"
            + "      'MAX(IF(`skillId` = ', `skillId`, ',levelId,NULL)) AS `',\n"
            + "      `skillId`, '`'\n"
            + "    )\n"
            + "  ) INTO @sql\n"
            + "FROM tblCandidateToSkill,candidateToJob,tblCandidate\n"
            + "where tblCandidateToSkill.candidateId = candidateToJob.candidateId and tblCandidate.id = candidateToJob.candidateId;";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(query);

    query = "SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  tblCandidateToSkill.candidateId,name,email,dob,phoneNumber,alternateNumber,addressLine, ', @sql, ' \n"
            + "                  FROM    tblCandidateToSkill,candidateToJob,tblCandidate\n"
            + "                 where tblCandidateToSkill.candidateId = candidateToJob.candidateId and tblCandidate.id = candidateToJob.candidateId\n"
            + "                 and candidateToJob.jobId= ? \n"
            + "                  GROUP   BY candidateId');";
    jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[]{currentJob.getId()});

    query = "PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(query);

    query = "EXECUTE stmt;";
    appliedCandidateList = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new RowMapper<CandidateDO>() {
        @Override
        public CandidateDO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            CandidateDO candidate = new CandidateDO();
            candidate.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            candidate.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            candidate.setDob(rs.getDate("dob"));
            candidate.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString("phoneNumber"));
            candidate.setAlternateNumber(rs.getString("alternateNumber"));
            candidate.setAddressLine(rs.getString("addressLine"));

            for (Iterator<SkillDO> it = currentJob.getSkills().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                SkillDO skill = it.next();

public List<CandidateDO> getCandidateList(final JobDO currentJob) {
    List<CandidateDO> appliedCandidateList = new ArrayList<CandidateDO>();
    CandidateDO candidate = new CandidateDO();
    String query = "SET @sql = NULL;";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(query);

    query = "SELECT\n"
            + "  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT\n"
            + "    CONCAT(\n"
            + "      'MAX(IF(`skillId` = ', `skillId`, ',levelId,NULL)) AS `',\n"
            + "      `skillId`, '`'\n"
            + "    )\n"
            + "  ) INTO @sql\n"
            + "FROM tblCandidateToSkill,candidateToJob,tblCandidate\n"
            + "where tblCandidateToSkill.candidateId = candidateToJob.candidateId and tblCandidate.id = candidateToJob.candidateId;";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(query);

    query = "SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  tblCandidateToSkill.candidateId,name,email,dob,phoneNumber,alternateNumber,addressLine, ', @sql, ' \n"
            + "                  FROM    tblCandidateToSkill,candidateToJob,tblCandidate\n"
            + "                 where tblCandidateToSkill.candidateId = candidateToJob.candidateId and tblCandidate.id = candidateToJob.candidateId\n"
            + "                 and candidateToJob.jobId= ? \n"
            + "                  GROUP   BY candidateId');";
    jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[]{currentJob.getId()});

    query = "PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(query);

    query = "EXECUTE stmt;";
    appliedCandidateList = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new RowMapper<CandidateDO>() {
        @Override
        public CandidateDO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            CandidateDO candidate = new CandidateDO();
            candidate.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            candidate.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            candidate.setDob(rs.getDate("dob"));
            candidate.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString("phoneNumber"));
            candidate.setAlternateNumber(rs.getString("alternateNumber"));
            candidate.setAddressLine(rs.getString("addressLine"));

            for (Iterator<SkillDO> it = currentJob.getSkills().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                SkillDO skill = it.next();
                SkillLevelDO CandidateSkillLevel = new SkillLevelDO();
                CandidateSkillLevel.setId(rs.getInt(String.valueOf(skill.getId())));
                candidate.getSkillLevel().add(CandidateSkillLevel);
                candidate.getSkills().add(skill);
            }
            return candidate;
        }
    });

    query = "DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(query);
    return appliedCandidateList;
}        SkillLevelDO CandidateSkillLevel = new SkillLevelDO();
                CandidateSkillLevel.setId(rs.getInt(String.valueOf(skill.getId())));
                candidate.getSkillLevel().add(CandidateSkillLevel);
                candidate.getSkills().add(skill);
            }
            return candidate;
        }
    });

    query = "DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(query);
    return appliedCandidateList;
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. You are doing something wrong in your query. Also, +1 on this question? really???

Comment: I didn't upvote , but I guess the upvote was because the query expects 1 parameter and he is also setting that one parameter , but still he gets that error message .

Comment: @deepakkumar , you need to debug and find which is the erroneous query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the reason for the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10898738/1060037).

Looks like the following query is having an issue.

```
query = "SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  tblCandidateToSkill.candidateId,name,email,dob,phoneNumber,alternateNumber,addressLine, ', @sql, ' \n"
        + "                  FROM    tblCandidateToSkill,candidateToJob,tblCandidate\n"
        + "                 where tblCandidateToSkill.candidateId = candidateToJob.candidateId and tblCandidate.id = candidateToJob.candidateId\n"
        + "                 and candidateToJob.jobId= ? \n"
        + "                  GROUP   BY candidateId');";
```

Your *single quotes* (') is suspicious. The (?) *PLACEHOLDER* inside the query is within the Single quotes which is just considered as *STRING* rather than a (?) *PLACEHOLDER*.