# Java Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)."

Tags: java, sql, sqlexception

I try to insert some data in the mySQL database using java swing! But i get the error

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).

Here's the java code that shows the error:

```
public void saveData(String data) {
    try {
        conn = MySQL_Connect.ConnectDb();
        String sql = "insert into parameterdata(stn_number ,time_received ,temperature_value "
                + ",ph_value ,moisture_value) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
        statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setInt(1, readStationNumber());
        statement.setString(2, data.substring(49, 50));
        statement.setString(3, data.substring(49, 50));
        statement.setString(4, data.substring(49, 50));
        statement.setString(5, data.substring(49, 50));
        statement.execute();
        System.out.println("Successfully saved!");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch (SQLException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("saveData() error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Can anyone show what could be the cause of the error?

Comment: This problem seems to have *nothing* to do with Swing (even if it is a Swing app.) and *everything* to do with SQL!  Please choose your tags more carefully in future, they are supposed to be related to the stated problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ...
    statement.executeUpdate();
    ...
}
```

That is, the statement has to be closed at some time, and it is better to not keep *reused* globals. A dedicated maybe `final` PreparedStatement would be fine.

**Maybe parallel executing code *changed* the statement under your feet; reassigning to `statement`.**