# insert single row with a preparedstatement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

i used this piece of code but it keeps turning me the exception **parameter index out of range** :

```
sql="insert into note (matricule) values(?)";
         ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         ps.setString(1,m);
         ps.execute();}
```

what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: add space between `values` and `(?)` in your sql expression. The resulting expression will be `sql="insert into note (matricule) values (?)"`

Comment: i added a space but i keep having the same error

Comment: MIght help http://stackoverflow.com/a/12968457/916225

Comment: @Moez rewrite your sql expression to make SQL keywords uppercase and make sure table name/field name are written correctly according to the letter case, SQL for MySQL is case sensitive: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: You *need* neither a space after `values` nor uppercase keywords. While that may fit with one person's view of how SQL should look, it's pretty much irrelevant to the question. I myself prefer lower case because I'm too lazy to reach for the SHIFT key :-)

Comment: thanks everybody i fixed it now everything is fine :)

Comment: @Moez, can we assume from the fact you accepted my answer that `sql` was indeed changed from what you have it as above? If not, you should probably self-answer and accept *that* rather than mine. If so, confirmation beyond "I fixed it" would be handy :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo  i found that the error comes from another part of my program and the answers here helped me figure out that my statement was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing intrinsically wrong with what you've shown us but the fact the statements are at different indent levels *may* mean the setting of `sql` is not immediately before the preparing of the statement.

If that *is* the case, make sure `sql` hasn't changed in the meantime (print it out immediately before preparing).

That's about the only way I can think that code would give you an index error, short of a rather fatal bug.