# Having an error in sql query in servlets

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

i want to fetch multiple row having same product name

```
String sql="select * from ayush where product = ? in (select product from ayush group by product having count(*)>1)";


String product=request.getParameter("search");
String sql="select * from ayush where product LIKE '%"+product+"%'";
```

I tried this like query but not working

It is giving an error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of
>   parameters, which is 0).

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). changed but now it giving this error

Comment: How does that make sense ? @sgeddes

Comment: means? can you tell me the syntax by considering my terms

Comment: @Yossi -- the question was edited since I commented -- it originally said `where product = ? in (` -- which obviously wasn't correct....

Comment: @sgeddes Oh , I see :P

Comment: ya i knw but also i didnt get correct syntax in my case

Comment: `product = ? in` what is this

Comment: Maybe `String sql="select * from ayush where product = ? and product in (select product from ayush group by product having count(*)>1)";` ?

Comment: am just trying i just want to fetch multiple product from product name getting from .getParameter("search"); can you just tell me the correct syntax

Comment: if field `product` in db means product name, then try this `select * from ayush where product LIKE '%?%'` assign `search` in param place holder `?`

Comment: WHERE to write search? @Yazan

Comment: i tried but java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set. giving this error @ammoQ

Comment: String product=request.getParameter("search");
  String sql="select * from ayush where product LIKE '%"+product+"%'"; i wrote like this @Yazan but giving this error java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: `Illegal operation on empty result set.` means the qry is OK and executed successfully  apperantly it returned no data (no records match search) so maybe you are trying to `.next()` on empty result set.

Comment: @Yazan its works but itz showing one product name

Comment: Hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh

Comment: thanks for help guys

Comment: i will let u know tommorow

Comment: if the result set reaches -end of list- you can't call `next()` to stay safe use a while-loop `while ( resultSet.next() ) {...` as `next()` will return true if it still have records.