# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).not getting how to resolve

Tags: mysql

```
public UserLoginDTO populateUserDetails(Connection conn, UserLoginDTO user) throws Exception {

    Log.info("Enter populateUserDetails()");
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    UserLoginDTO userDetail=null;

    try 
    {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(QueryConstant.GET_USER_DETAILS.toString());
        pstmt.setInt(1, user.getUserId());
        //pstmt.setString(1, user.getUserName());
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            userDetail= new UserLoginDTO();
            userDetail.setUserId(rs.getInt("M_USER_ID"));
            userDetail.setUserTypeID(rs.getInt("USER_TYPE_ID"));
            userDetail.setUserName(rs.getString("M_USER_NAME"));
            userDetail.setLoginID(rs.getString("LOGIN_ID"));
            userDetail.setPassword(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    } 
    finally 
    {
        ConnectionManager.close(null, null, rs, pstmt);
    }

    Log.info("Exit populateUserDetails()");
    return userDetail;
}
```

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Why is such an exception occurring and how to resolve it?

Comment: What line is producing the error?

Comment: public static final StringBuilder GET_USER_DETAILS = new StringBuilder().
 append("select UD.M_User_ID,UD.M_User_NAME,UD.PASSWORD,UD.USER_TYPE_ID,UD.M_Login_ID").
 append(" from M_USER_Master UD , M_USER_TYPE_Master CTM ").
 append(" WHERE UD.USER_TYPE_ID = CTM.USER_TYPE_ID ");

Comment: @pie3636 it is not going in while next() execution loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh)

Answer (score 0):

Your `GET_USER_DETAILS` is supposed to contain question marks whenever parameters should be replaced.

For example, if `GET_USER_DETAILS` is

```
"SELECT <...> FROM <...> WHERE UD.USER_TYPE_ID = ?"
```

Then you can do

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(QueryConstant.GET_USER_DETAILS.toString());
pstmt.setInt(1, user.getUserId());
```

And the question mark in the query will be replaced with the value of `user.getUserId()`.

Here your `GET_USER_DETAILS` was apparently equal to

```
SELECT UD.M_User_ID,UD.M_User_NAME, UD.PASSWORD, UD.USER_TYPE_ID, UD.M_Login_ID
FROM   M_USER_Master UD, M_USER_TYPE_Master CTM
WHERE  UD.USER_TYPE_ID = CTM.USER_TYPE_ID
```

There are no question marks in it, so the driver doesn't know what are the parameters that it can set, meaning it doesn't know what to replace with `user.getUserId()`