# SELECT query not passing parameters

Tags: mysql

I have an select query with inner join, and the where clause is in the second Query,

Here is the code :

```
static String Showplan = "SELECT * From plan_audit INNER JOIN (SELECT Du,Au From Programme_audit Where Du = '?' AND Au = '?')AS T ";

public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        try{
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            Core.con = DriverManager.getConnection(Core.db,Core.dbUsername,Core.dbPassword);
                            PreparedStatement st;
                            st = Core.con.prepareStatement(Core.Showplan);
                            st.setString(1,select.getValue().toString());
                            st.setString(2,select1.getValue().toString());
                            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

                            while(rs.next()){
                                table.addItem(new Object[]{rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getDate(3),rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getDate(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11),rs.getDate(12),rs.getString(13),rs.getString(14),rs.getString(15)},rs.getInt(1));

                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }


            });
```

and the exception being raised is the following:

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of
>   parameters, which is 0).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put single quotes after the parameter markers `?`.  In fact, don't do *anything* to them, rather let Java insert the data as it sees fit:

```
String sql = "SELECT * From plan_audit INNER JOIN ";
sql += "(SELECT Du, Au From Programme_audit Where Du = ? AND Au = ?) t ";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1, select.getValue().toString());
st.setString(2, select1.getValue().toString());
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

The whole point of prepared statements is to let Java worry about how to bring your data into the query.  In this case, since you are binding strings, they would be surrounded by single quotes, but you do not need to be concerned with this.

As a side note, your query is actually doing a cross join, since you never specify a join condition.  This may or may not be what you intend, but most likely you want to have some kind of join condition here.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is display records in a date interval that is set in the joined query, so i'd appreciate an elaboration on your behalf on using cross join

Comment: @BendaoudAchraf I can't answer that without seeing your data and expected output.  Besides this, it is very different than your original question.  You should probably ask a new question for the query logic (and leave out the Java part, which hopefully you have working now).

Comment: i fixed the query logic also, now i have it dispalying the correct records using inner join, since the joined select query served only a "where" clause a sort of condition if you may, Thank you for your help

Comment: Good on you for fixing the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the parameter indexes 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2?

```
st.setString(0,select.getValue().toString());
st.setString(1,select1.getValue().toString());
```

The single quotes are correct.

Comment: Parameters are (for whatever reason) indexed beginning at 1, not 0.  So your suggestion won't fix the problem.

Comment: I remember having used those single quotes many times before (and indexes starting at 1), but my JDBC implementation was probably a different one than this - and you were right in this case.

Comment: Yes...it's possible that a different driver does start at 0.  Most SO questions are using the standard drivers for the major databases, and those all start at index 1 (I think).