# #0001: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I want to delete a row. My TABLES are 'goal' and 'contribute'.It shows above error. 
Please tell immediately what's the problem.

Table structure is ,

```
 //goal TABLE
 CREATE TABLE `goal` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(555) NOT NULL,
`target_value` double NOT NULL,
 `target_date` date NOT NULL,
`created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci   
 //Contribute TABLE 
CREATE TABLE `contribute` 
(`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`goal` int(11) NOT NULL,
`amount` double NOT NULL, `date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),KEY `idgoal_idx` (`goal`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`goal`) REFERENCES `goal` (`id`))
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8m
COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

//Code

```
public static boolean delete(int id) {

    try {
        Connection con = DB.getConnection();

        String sql = "ALTER TABLE 'goal' ADD CONSTRAINT 'fk' FOREIGN 
        KEY('goal') REFERENCES 'goal' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setInt(1, id);

        ps.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: What's your table structure?

Comment: added the table structure .

Comment: @ManojChathuranga I anwser it below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two problem:

1.your sql doesn't contain any parameter keyword : `?`

You use java set parameter `ps.setInt(1, id)`, but your sql doesn't contain keyword `?`

Example for parameter using `?` :

```
PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("select * from xxxTable where xxx = ?");
p.setString(1, xxx);
```

More details you can learn from [mysql - java.sql.SQLException Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh)

---

2.Your SQL maybe wrong

```
ALTER TABLE 'goal' ADD CONSTRAINT 'fk' FOREIGN 
    KEY('goal') REFERENCES 'goal' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE
```

'goal' table doesn't contain 'goal' column.

it should be changed like:

```
ALTER TABLE `contribute`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`goal`) REFERENCES `goal`(`id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE ;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b49574/1/0)

Comment: do you remove `ps.setInt(1, id)`?

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion your code is bad. You are executing this

`String sql = "ALTER TABLE 'goal' ADD CONSTRAINT 'fk' FOREIGN 
               KEY('goal') REFERENCES 'goal' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ";`

every time you invoke this method. You should add constraints when creating the tables.
In order to delete a row from some table i suggest you to create a database procedure or function which does it and invoke it through java.

```
String sql = "{? = call your_schema.your_package.delete_object(?)}";

try (CallableStatement cs = con.createCallableStatement(sql)) {
     cs.setInt(1, id);
     cs.executeQuery();
}
```

This is just an example but i think this is the correct way to do it. In this procedure you accept your ID as parameter and delete the row there.