# How to fix 'java.sql.SQLException' error when I insert data in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Im using preparedStatement, and i have java.sql.SQLException error

```
query = "INSERT INTO instdb (" +
     "id," +
     "name," +
     "username," +
     "descr," +
     "tel," +
     "vk," +
     "ownerId," +
     "query," +
     "postId," +
     "parametr) VALUES" +
     "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setInt(1, maxid);
stmt.setString(2,user.getFull_name());
stmt.setString(3,username);
stmt.setString(4,caption);
stmt.setString(5,longestTel);
stmt.setString(6,vk);
stmt.setString(7,ownerId);
stmt.setString(8,addons.get(j));
stmt.setString(9,postId);
stmt.setString(10,param);
```

And on `stmt.setInt(1, maxid);` error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

**EDIT 1**

I replace `stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);` and have a new error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
```

P.S.
That didnt help me [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh)

Comment: Where are you assigning the value of query string to stmt?

Comment: I assign stmt with now that query and have that error. I replace assigning and have a new error

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to initilaize `stm`?

```
stm = con.prepareStatement(query);
```

where `con` is your `Connection` object.

Comment: I assign stmt with now that query and have that error. I replace assigning and have a new error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not assigning the query string to the prepared statement.  Should be something like:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

stmt.setInt(1, maxid);
```

etc.
 ... ...

Comment: I assign stmt with now that query and have that error. I replace assigning and have a new error

Comment: Then open a new question.  You cannot morph one question into another.  Your initial question was answered.