# Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 2)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am making a simple java jdbc program where I have to insert a user history on table but got stock on there. Here is my code

```
public void insertIntoHistory(ArrayList<QuestionAnswer> questionAnswer) throws Exception {
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        int maxId = getMaxSets() + 1;

        for (QuestionAnswer qa : questionAnswer) {
            String getSql = "INSERT INTO userhist(id, questionid, "
                    + "givenanswerid, isCorrect, questionSet) "
                    + "VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)";

            pst = conn.prepareStatement(getSql);
            pst.setInt(1, qa.getQuestionId());
            pst.setInt(2, qa.getAnswerId());
            pst.setBoolean(3, (isCorrect(qa.getQuestionId(), qa.getAnswerId())));
            pst.setInt(4, maxId);

            pst.executeUpdate();
        }

        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        conn.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The error is :

> Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 0).
>   java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of
>   parameters, which is 0).  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3813)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3795)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3840)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInt(PreparedStatement.java:3784)
>     at HistoryController.insertIntoHistory(HistoryController.java:37)   at
>   MultipleChoiseQuestion.jButton2ActionPerformed(MultipleChoiseQuestion.java:223)
>     at MultipleChoiseQuestion.access$700(MultipleChoiseQuestion.java:20)
>     at
>   MultipleChoiseQuestion$7.actionPerformed(MultipleChoiseQuestion.java:141)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)    at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

I think problem came from this method

```
private boolean isCorrect(int questionId, int ansId) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM correctanswer where questionid = ? and answerid = ?";
    boolean isCorrect = false;

    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, questionId);
        pst.setInt(2, ansId);

        ResultSet res = pst.executeQuery();
        int count = 0;
        if (res.next()) {
            count = res.getInt(1);
        }

        isCorrect = count > 1;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

    return isCorrect;
}
```

this is my table structure
[image]

What is happening here please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh)

Comment: @Yserbius That didn't solve my issue please can you look at into it

Comment: Probably we have this weird behavioral because of general unclarity.

1. Please create prepared statement once before loop and then do set and execution in loop. Also you have to close statement after execution (consider `try (...) {....}`).
 
2. Another question, are you sure exception came from this method but not from  `getMaxSets()` ?

Comment: What database are you using? Can you also post your schema?

Comment: @Nikolary Antipov, Please could you look at my updated question.

Comment: @ChrisHadfield What database are you using? MariaDB? PostGres? SQL Server?

Comment: @Yserbius - MySql

Comment: @ChrisHadfield, thanks for adding more details. In general I would suggest to reconsider the overall process as you have lots of statements opened and never closed.
Nevertheless, could you please show the entire stacktrace? And let us know the database type as Yserbius suggested?

Comment: @NikolayAntipov - please look at the updated question

Comment: @ChrisHadfield, show please full Java stacktrace and database type (mysql ?).

Comment: remove the id insertion

Comment: @NikolayAntipov - Please look at the full stack trace

Comment: It looks like `pst` is a field, and you are possibly overwriting it with concurrent access to the same object. You should generally try to keep references to JDBC types local variables to a method, or otherwise you must make sure to use unique fields, or correctly synchronize access. However, to be sure we would need to see a [mre].

Comment: Yes, I think @MarkRotteveel is right. Good catch! Field `pst` is re-used among the class and its usage is hardly controllable. I did not notice that `pst` is not a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may stem from you trying to insert a `NULL` into the `id` column. Since it's auto-increment not-null, you should pretend it doesn't exist for the purpose of `INSERT` commands.

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a new instance of PrepareStatement inside `isCorrect` method.
Thanks for your response