# I can't store data localhost(database) using java netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, localhost

. I am still new to programming and I really don't know what else should I do, watched lots of Youtube videos but non of them work.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jc.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at RegisterForm.buttregActionPerformed(RegisterForm.java:458)
    at RegisterForm.access$300(RegisterForm.java:24)
    at RegisterForm$4.actionPerformed(RegisterForm.java:153)
```

I have already made a database and also the table in the localhost, when it I press the register button it won't store the user inputted.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jc.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userinterface_?serverTimezone=UTC","root","");
            ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO 'java_login_register'('fname', 'lname', 'uname', 'pass','gender','phono',bdate','address') VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Above is my code to store the user inputted to the database. ineedhelp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you connection string is an problem , try to the reference [Website](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html)

Comment: I don't understand the reference website, i tried searching it but i don't seem to understand how that works. im so sorryyy please be understanding with me :'(

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") to load and register this driver class, the class loader in JVM search for this class inside all JAR files available in CLASSPATH. If mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar, which contains this class is not available in CLASSPATH then JVM will throw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at run-time.

Comment: hello sir, I am now getting this message in my output box 
" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)."

Comment: Kindly review the resource https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh