# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0) Problem

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Can anyone teach me where I went wrong?

```
private void Submit_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
           
    if (First_Name.getText().isEmpty() || Last_Name.getText().isEmpty() || Contact_Number.getText().isEmpty() ){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Fill Up The Forms");            
        clear();
    }
    //First_Name.getText();
    //Last_Name.getText();
    //Contact_Number.getText();
    else{
        try{                
            String query = "INSERT INTO `user2`(`First Name`, `Last Name`, `Contact Number`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registration?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","");
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            //pst.setString
            pst.setString(0, First_Name.getText());
            pst.setString(1, Last_Name.getText());
            pst.setString(2,Contact_Number.getText());
            pst.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(Contact_Number.getText()));
            
            pst.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Registered");
            clear();
        }
        catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why set 4 parameters when there are only 3 in the query?

Comment: JDBC prepared statement parameters are numbered from 1, not 0. In addition, you are trying to set 4 parameters when there are only three, the last two sets being for the same parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting 4 parameters when the sql-string only contains three "?".

Also the parameters are set starting from 1 and not 0.
See this answer for more detailed info: [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh)