# Spring Security SQLException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have attached spring security to my learning project. I decided to follow this  [tutorial:](https://tutorials.webencyclop.com/spring-boot/03-create-user-login-registration/#define-controllers-for-login-registration)
But when when i am trying to log in, i get **java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).**

Server log:

I spent many hours trying to find out what is wrong. But still can``t understand why it isn`t working.

MySecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
@Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
private String usersQuery;

@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String rolesQuery;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            // URLs matching for access rights
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/home/**").hasAnyAuthority("SUPER_USER", "ADMIN_USER", "SITE_USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()

            // form login
            .csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            // logout
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
   }


}
```

MyController:

```
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {

@RequestMapping(value = { "/login" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    modelAndView.setViewName("login"); 
    return modelAndView;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView register() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    // User user = new User();
    // modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
    modelAndView.setViewName("register"); 
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public ModelAndView home() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("home"); 
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

and jsp:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
   <title>English - login</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form th:action="@{/login}" method="POST">
      Login
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" th:placeholder="Email"/>
      <br>
      Password
      <br>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" th:placeholder="Password"/>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit" th:text="Login"></button>
      <a href="/recover-password">Forgot password?</a>
      </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

my properties file:

```
 #Spring Security login queries
 security.basic.enabled=false
 spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, '1' as enabled from auth_user where email=? and  status='VERIFIED'
 spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role_name from auth_user u inner join auth_user_role ur on(u.auth_user_id=ur.auth_user_id) inner join auth_role r on(ur.auth_role_id=r.auth_role_id) where u.email=?
```

As I can see, parameters from my page go to Controller:

[image]

The problem, as I understood with sql statement. But as for me, my sql statements are like default ones in JdbcDaoImpl.class. I looked all the solutions here according this exception by didn`t find the answer. Please help. I hope that I have attached all the neccesary information. If any code also should be attached here - please write.

I tried to rebuild my tables in other way (2 tables - users and authorities), tried use '?' and ? in sql statement, tried to change search from email to username. And it`s not working(

Link to project GITHUB
https://github.com/SerhiiRyzhkov/english

Comment: this question is already answered in s[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896151/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-wh)
refer this

Comment: you are passing a string rather than the variable `usersQuery` which holds the actual sql query here - `auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery("usersQuery")`

Comment: @Neeraj but method usersByUsernameQuery wait for String, not for query accrding to JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.class. I don`t see there any methods called usersByUsernameQuery with queries there. Only with String

Comment: @sachin at you link, author did not have a placeholder "?" in his statement and that was his problem. But I have "?" in my statement. So we have the same Exception but different reasons as for me. And that question did not help me(

Answer (score 1):

I think in your configuration file you are passing usersQuery as a string value with double quotes instead of passing the variable that holds an actual query in string format.
Because in the query you have a placeholder '?' for a parameter not in "usersQuery" string and it is not even an actual query.

Try by changing your configuration to:

> auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
> .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it realy was a mistake. I made the mistake after trying various options to transfer the string there (I also tried to get the a string without annotation and property file and other ways). And forgot to correct that before posting here. Now I have fixed that and added to the question, but still have the problem java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).